# My megane 1.6 2005 is running poorly

Tags: engine, misfire, renault, megane

My megane just started running poorly miss firing , loss of power and a horrible fuel smell got it on a diagnostic machine it said camshaft position sensor .Ive just replaced that and its still running bad as anyone got any other ideas what it could be

Comment: does the car have variable valve timing? if so check your oil level it may be low. also if it does the oil control valve may be stuck open. or a cam phaser is stuck. or the cam crank timing ia off.

Comment: Check your oil first. Always. Drop a few drips of water on each exhaust pipe to see if you just have a single cylinder misfiring. It may simply be a fouled plug or something specific to a single cylinder.